# Two or more ajax calls to one PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked and I looked the other topics, but couldn not find an answer.

I have two ajax calls, that point to the same page. One deletes language selection and other one deletes education experience. Weird thing is that the last query on PHP page works (at the moment language).

EDIT:
Why is the first query not working? (when trying to delete education exp)

---

PHP

```
/*------------------------------------------
[NANY EDUCATION EXP DELETE]
-------------------------------------------*/ 
if(isset($_POST['education_id']) && !empty($_POST['education_id'])){
    $education_id = $_POST['education_id'];
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("DELETE FROM user_education WHERE education_id=:education_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':education_id' => $education_id));
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
}else{
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';

}

/*------------------------------------------
[NANY LANGUAGE EXP DELETE]
-------------------------------------------*/ 
if(isset($_POST['language_id']) && !empty($_POST['language_id'])){
    $language_id = $_POST['language_id'];
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("DELETE FROM user_language WHERE language_id=:language_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':language_id' => $language_id));
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
}else{
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';

}
```

JS

---

```
            /*------------------------------------------
            [NANY EDUCATION EXP DELETE]
            -------------------------------------------*/ 
            $(document).on("click", ".deleteEducationEXP", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var education_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:'PHP/deleteData.php',
                    data:"education_id=" + education_id,
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data.status == 'success'){
                            console.log("success"); 
                        }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                            console.log("error"); 
                        }
                    },      
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
                        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
                    } 
                });
            });

            /*------------------------------------------
            [NANY LANGUAGE EXP DELETE]
            -------------------------------------------*/ 
            $(document).on("click", ".deleteLangugage", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var language_id = $(this).attr('id'); 
                $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(300, function() { $(this).remove(); });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:'PHP/deleteData.php',
                    data:"language_id=" + language_id,
                    success:function(data){
                        if(data.status == 'success'){
                            console.log("success"); 
                        }else if(data.status == 'error'){
                            console.log("error"); 
                        }
                    },                
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data){
                        console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown, data);
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: Did you forget to ask a question? What's the help you need?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there's no question here.

Comment: @PraveenKumar oops. I edited. Kindly see the edit

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] instead of the huge amount of code you have there; if the error involves accessing a database, explain the database's structure and give sample values for it

Comment: What does "not working" meen exactly? Got an error?

Comment: In your JS, try checking the value of `var education_id = $(this).attr('id'); ` maybe it is somehow getting empty value and hence in PHP `! empty( $_POST['education_id'] )` is returning `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that both `else` clauses set `$response_array['status'] = "error";`.

When they delete education, the first `if` block succeeds, deletes from the education table and sets `$response_array['status'] = "success";`. Then it goes to the next `if` block, which fails and overwrites `$reponse_array['status']`.

Use `elseif` to combine them.

```
if(!empty($_POST['education_id'])){
    /*------------------------------------------
    [NANY EDUCATION EXP DELETE]
    -------------------------------------------*/ 
    $education_id = $_POST['education_id'];
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("DELETE FROM user_education WHERE education_id=:education_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':education_id' => $education_id));
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
}elseif(!empty($_POST['language_id'])){
    /*------------------------------------------
    [NANY LANGUAGE EXP DELETE]
    -------------------------------------------*/ 
    $language_id = $_POST['language_id'];
    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("DELETE FROM user_language WHERE language_id=:language_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':language_id' => $language_id));
    $response_array['status'] = 'success';
}else{
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
}
```

BTW, you don't need to use both `isset()` and `!empty()`, since `empty()` checks whether it's set first.

Comment: Thanks you sir! Working great now. Really appreciate your help.